# Reverse filter for SQL show query. "Show Fields from xtable where Field = xFieldnameA = a AND Field = xFieldnameB

Tags: mysql, information-schema

This concerns sql show queries. The following query below **works** the issue is it seems I must tell mysql which field names I *don't want* rather than those I do (which is preferred).

e.g. (working)

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM users WHERE Field != 'uid' AND Field != 'fk_Utype'
```

The above executes perfectly as expected, stipping off both 'uid' and 'fk_Utype' from the result set. However when querying by which columns I only want (like a traditional Select query) listing the column names needed does not behave as expected.

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM users WHERE Field = 'firstName' AND Field = 'lastName'
```

I expected the above query to simply return the two specified columns. However, the query instead results in an empty result set (the columns *do* exist in that table and appear when the above query is executed). Clearly I'm not listing the desired column names correctly. As in a Select statement the syntax it simply 'Select col1, col2' but this syntax is incorrect in a SHOW query (though I may well be mistaken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM users WHERE Field = 'firstName' OR Field = 'lastName'
```

AND means both conditions must be true whereas OR means either condition can be true.

Answer (score -1):

Try below query

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM users WHERE Field == 'firstName' AND Field == 'lastName'
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion though this was not the cause. Many thanks.

Comment: what would you get if you execute `SHOW FIELDS FROM users`